# .net maui change graphics view width and height to size of window or screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I have simple graphics view

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <GraphicsView x:Name="modelerArea"
        Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
                  HeightRequest="1000"
                  WidthRequest="1000" />
```

And I want to set width and height to size of window or screen. How can I achieve that?
From xaml.cs file I tried something like this but I get error because field its readonly

```
    double height = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
    double width = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
    modelerArea.Width = width;
    modelerArea.Height = height;
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You can only set the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` properties in MAUI (and Xamarin.Forms). The other properties are read-only and provide the actually calculated dimensions whereas you can only request a certain width or height, but those values are not guaranteed. If you want to fill the entire space that is available, you could also use `HorizontalOptions = "Fill"` and `VerticalOptions = "Fill"` in your XAML, but then you shouldn't set `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` at the same time as they would override the stretching behavior.

Comment: Thank you for valuable information. It works now :) Please if possible rewrite your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fill the entire available space would be to simply use the `GraphicsView` as the only content item and use the `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` to stretch it:

```xml
<ContentPage ...>
    <GraphicsView x:Name="modelerArea"
                  Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
</ContentPage>
```

More information on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/align-position?view=net-maui-7.0

Alternatively, in your code-behind you could also use the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` properties of the `GraphicsView`:

```cs
modelerArea.WidthRequest = width;
modelerArea.HeightRequest = height;
```

This is necessary, because `Width` and `Height` are read-only properties that only provide the actually calculated on-screen dimensions. The values of `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` are not guaranteed.

**Note:** You cannot use both approaches at the same time, because the `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` and `VerticalOptions="Fill"` will override the requested width and height values.